# netbeans - how to change keymap for CTRL+7

Tags: netbeans

Anyone know if its possible to remap CTRL+7?

Coming from eclipse I'm looking for a shortcut for "goto method". I've re-mapped all my other favourite shortcuts but this one is eluding me. CTRL+7 seems to be the netbeans equivalent of eclipses CTRL+O but I can't see it in the netbeans keymap.

I've looked though all the actions in Tools -> Options -> Keymap. I can't see CTRL+7 in there nor I can see an action which sounds/looks like "goto navigator".

[image]

Netbeans 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In, Tools->Options->Keymap, I typed CTRL+7 in the "Search in Shortcuts" text field. This lists the following action:

```
Navigator | Ctrl+7 | Window
```

You can click the "..." menu button to clear the shortcut so that you can re-use it for a different action.

Comment: Weird. I've added a screenshot of what I get when searching for CTRL+7 :(
What version of netbeans you running?

Comment: I'm running NetBeans 8.1 and 8.2 on Windows.I checked and found Ctrl+7 in both. I also checked NetBeans 8.1 running in Centos 7 and I see it there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the testing, much appreciated. I guess I need to raise a ticket with the netbeans guys.

Comment: you're kidding me, I've just checked again (after computer restart) and now it appears!!!